# How to count the elements in a SectionCollection using PageObject

Tags: page-object-gem

Pretty much says what I want in the title. tried

```
col.length
and 
col_elements.length
```

Neither seem to work.

Comment: If `col_elements` is the method generated by the `sections` accessor, then `col_elements.length` will work. Therefore, can you explain how you have defined `col_elements` and what do you mean by it does not work?

Answer (score 0):

Justin Ko responded on the premise of HTML5 sections, however I think you may be referring to PageSections of which SectionCollections are enumerable. This means you can leverage the .size method to find out the count of elements in your sectionCollection.

```
col.count
```

That call should solve your question. The .size & .length methods are for Array objects and are not available for Enumerables.